# What is a linear isomorphism between $\underset{n\times m}{\times} \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

What is a linear isomorphism between 
$\underset{n\times m}{\times} \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathbb{R}^m$?

Where $n\times m :=\{(i,j):0\le n-1,0\le j \le m-1\}$.

Since $\underset{n\times m}{\times} \mathbb{R}$ consists of $nm$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$ it has dimension $nm$. Also $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathbb{R}^m$ has dimension $nm$. Hence they must be isomorphic as vector spaces.

Now what is a map $\psi:\underset{n\times m}{\times} \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathbb{R}^m$ that gives this isomorphism?

So what is $\psi(w_{i,j})$? Where $w_{i,j}:n\times m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $v_i$ are a basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $w_j$ are a basis of $\Bbb{R}^m$, then $v_i \otimes w_j$ are a basis of $\Bbb{R}^n \otimes \Bbb{R}^m$. So just order these $v_1 \otimes w_1$, $v_1 \otimes w_2$, ..., etc, and map these to the basis vectors of $\Bbb{R}^{mn}$.

Comment: You say "**the** linear isomorphism". Note that "the" is the singular definite article, and implies uniqueness: there is one linear isomorphism, or there is a prefered linear isomorphism. There is no such thing here; you should ask for " **a** linear isomorphism".

Comment: **The** map is the wrong question. Trivially, there are *many* linear isomorphisms between both spaces because have the same dimension.

Comment: Your both right; I replaced it by a

Comment: Are you thinking of $\times_{n\times m}\mathbb{R}$ as the vector space of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$? If so, there is a *natural* isomorphism $\text{Hom}_F(V,W) \to W\otimes V^*$ for any finite-dimensional $F$-vector spaces $V,W$, which may be more satisfying than choosing two arbitrary bases and identifying them. Of course, you'll need to choose bases to identify linear maps with matrices in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{e_1^n, \dots, e_n^n\}$ be the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\{e_1^m, \dots, e_m^m\}$ be the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Then a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes \mathbb{R}^m$ is given by $\{e_i^n \otimes e_j^m: 0 \le i \le n-1, 0 \le j \le m -1 \}$.

We define $\psi(w_{i,j}) = \sum_{i,j}w_{i,j} \; e_i^n \otimes e_j^m$.